# How to handle different pin names based on package

Tags: origen-sdk

We're importing our pins into the dut model by parsing xml design documents, which lists different pin names based on the package:

```
  <pin name="mypin" direction="input">
   <package_list>
    <package package="pkg_a" name="mypin_a" location="XX" direction="input"/>
    <package package="pkg_b" name="mypin_b" location="XX" direction="input"/>
   </package_list>
  </pin>
```

This is the same pin, just a different name depending on its package.
In my ruby flow files, depending on the test insertion I set the package so that I get the correct pins when accessing the dut models pins.

Is there currently a way to access the same pin but change its name depending on the package? As in, when using the above example, how would I get this behavior?

```
Package     Pin Name
--------------------
nil         mypin
pkg_a       mypin_a
pkg_b       mypin_b
```

I see in the [origen documentation](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/api/Origen/Pins/Pin.html) that there are package-scoped and function-scoped attributes, but there doesn't seem to be a way to rename the pin based on package that I am seeing, assuming I'm reading the docs correctly.

Would this functionality require an extension to the package-scoped attributes feature? Or is there a simpler way via some fancy aliasing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is the same physical pin, does it need to be modeled that way if the different names are mutually exclusive?

e.g. While this will be modeled as 3 separate pin objects, only one of the them would be available in each of the 3 package options and so it should behave like you want:

```rb
add_package :none
add_package :pkg_a
add_package :pkg_b

add_pin :mypin,   package: :none,  direction: :input
add_pin :mypin_a, package: :pkg_a, direction: :input
add_pin :mypin_b, package: :pkg_b, direction: :input
```

I guess what you probably want though, is to be able to call `dut.pin(:mypin)` in each package scope and have it return the pin with the correct ID for the current package, however I couldn't find a way to get such an alias to work correctly.
Such a package-scoped alias is something that perhaps we need to consider adding to Origen.

In the meantime, perhaps you could get by with a helper method in your application?

```rb
def find_pin(id)
  dut.pins("#{id}_#{dut.package.id.to_s.sub('pkg_', '')")
end

dut.package = :pkg_a

pin = find_pin(:mypin)
pin.id    # => :mypin_a

dut.package = :pkg_b

pin = find_pin(:mypin)
pin.id    # => :mypin_b
```

Comment: In this example :none is not a alias for nil, it's setting a dummy package that represents the concept of no package. So if you say package = :none, then dut.pins should return only the subset of pins defined for that "package".

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the pin meta data hash - each pin has a meta data hash in which you can store whatever you like:

```rb
add_package :pkg_a
add_package :pkg_b

add_pin :mypin, package: :all, direction: :input,
                meta: { names: { pkg_a: "mypin_a", pkg_b: "mypin_b"}}
```

Then you get the single pin defined and you can retrieve the package-specific name pretty easily in your application code:

```rb
origen(main):002:0> dut.package = :pkg_a
=> :pkg_a
origen(main):007:0> dut.pin(:mypin).meta[:names][dut.package.id]
=> "mypin_a"
origen(main):008:0> dut.package = :pkg_b
=> :pkg_b
origen(main):009:0> dut.pin(:mypin).meta[:names][dut.package.id]
=> "mypin_b"
```